# How to insert null value in Database through parameterized query

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, insert, parameterized-query

I have a `datetime` datatype : `dttm`

Also the database field type is `datatime`

Now I am doing this:

```
if (dttm.HasValue)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtb", dttm);
}
else
{
    // It should insert null value into database
    // through cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtb", _____)
}
```

How can this be done.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx  : The value to be added. Use DBNull.Value instead of null, to indicate a null value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `DBNull.Value`

```
if (dttm.HasValue)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtb", dttm);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtb", DBNull.Value)
}
```

Answer (score 45):

This can be done using the  null-coalescing operator: if the value of dttm is null the DBNull.Value will be inserted otherwise the value of dttm will be used

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtb", dttm ?? (object) DBNull.Value);
```

This will eliminate the need for the if statment

Comment: Yup, this is the cleanest approach. I wasn't entirely sure of the viability of casting in the second operand of the null coalescing operator, but it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

if your field allows null value;

```
if (dttm.HasValue)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtb", dttm);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtb", DBNull.Value)
}
```