# How to add null values into database

Tags: c#

I am trying to add some data into my database. I have 5 columns which all allow null values and all have datatype of `varchar`. But in my program I am passing only 4 values and fifth column should be empty. When I do this shows error

> Number of supplied values does not match in the number of databse columns

How can I add `NULL` values into database?

My button click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string str=mas.empdetedit(ddid.SelectedItem.Text,txtname.Text,txtcon.text,txtval.text);
    }
```

My class is

```
public string empdetedit(string id, string name, string con, string val)
{
    string str=insert into table values('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+con+"','"+val+"'");
    conn.nonquery(str);
}
```

Comment: Please provide at least compiling code.

Comment: Soner Gönül, How you edited my question like this??I cant type question like this format

Comment: possible sql injection..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert null value in Database through parameterized query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717179/how-to-insert-null-value-in-database-through-parameterized-query)

Comment: Please take a tutorial with database record manipulation. Now you asking questions step after step: how insert null, date, boolean...

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee: indenting your code with 4 spaces will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to insert into only specific columns of a table is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (value1,value2,value3)
```

You are not explicitly specifying the column names, so the database thinks you are giving values for all of them.

Comment: And also: use a **parametrized query** to do the insert to avoid SQL injection attacks!